# Konami Code Keybinding in jQuery 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, version, compatibility, key-bindings

I'd like to implement the [`raptorize-Plugin`](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-raptorize) but it doesn't work with *jQuery 1.7.2* because of this part I think:

```
else if(options.enterOn == 'konami-code'){
            var kkeys = [], konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65";
            $(window).bind("keydown.raptorz", function(e){
                kkeys.push( e.keyCode );
                if ( kkeys.toString().indexOf( konami ) >= 0 ) {
                    init();
                    $(window).unbind('keydown.raptorz');
                }
            }, true);
```

When I use the `button-version` it works. What could be the problem?

Comment: What does not work? Do you receive an error message, either on screen or in your browser's console?

Comment: My browser console says
TypeError: ((f.event.special[s.origType] || {}).handle || s.handler).apply is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .bind() on line 93 of http://www.zurb.com/playground/javascripts/plugins/jquery.raptorize.1.0.js uses the third parameter to prevent bubbling, not sure why this would be necessary when we're looking for keydown events on window, but it's what is breaking it in newer jQuery versions. Remove that third param and it will work in 1.7.2.

Also ensure you are setting the option correctly e.g.:

```
$('.myButton').raptorize({
   'enterOn' : 'konami-code'
});
```

Comment: Thank you Tjkoopa but which third param do you exactly mean?
`var kkeys = [], konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65";
       $(window).bind("keydown.raptorz", function(e){
           kkeys.push( e.keyCode );
           if ( kkeys.toString().indexOf( konami ) >= 0 ) {
            init();
            $(window).unbind('keydown.raptorz');
           }`

Comment: In that bind() call, the first param is 'keydown.raptorz', the second is the callback and the third is the bool to set preventBubbling - remove the third, it's on line 99.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the [Mousetrap](http://craig.is/killing/mice) library instead of jQuery for this.

There's even a Konami Code example on the page linked above, done in a single line of JS code.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since original raptorize plugin was released (2010) and newer jQuery versions break it unfortunately. There is an updated implementation (https://github.com/randomvlad/raptorize-jquery) that supports jQuery versions 1.7+, 2.x and 3.x along with a few extra improvements.

Specifically logic for `konami-code` has been adjusted:

```js
} else if (options.enterOn === 'konami-code') {
    var keysPressed = [];
    var konamiCode = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65";
    $(window).on("keydown.raptorz", function (e) {
        keysPressed.push(e.keyCode);

        if (keysPressed.length > 10) {
            keysPressed = keysPressed.slice(1);
        }

        if (keysPressed.toString() === konamiCode) {
            animateRaptor();
        }
    });
}
```

Changes:

- Replace deprecated jQuery `bind()` with `on()`.
- Allow konami-code to be used more than once.
- Optimize to track and compare only the last 10 keystrokes.

Disclaimer: I'm the "author" of the updated raptorize 2.0 plugin, which itself is based on the original one by ZURB (https://zurb.com/playground/jquery-raptorize).